# Can we connect several Nano Spacecraft moving at 20% speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, rocket-science, space-travel, nanoscience

[Nano spacecrafts](https://newatlas.com/self-healing-nano-spacecraft-nasa-kaist/46890/) are one gram silicon chips that will be accelerated to 20% of the speed of light to reach Alpha Centauri in 20 years.

I wonder could we connect several spacecraft after they were accelerated to form a more sophisticated spacecraft? For example, the first one could have a radiation protection shield, but no navigation nor any other tools, then the next few will only have cameras. Finally, the last spacecraft will have a navigation system that will help them catch all the rest and form one big spacecraft.

Comment: I thought the idea was for them to all be identical so that many can malfunction without causing a problem.

Comment: My idea doesn't contradict it. You can still have multiple big spacecraft. I am just trying to find a solution to the weight limit.

Comment: This is an engineering problem, not a physics problem. I would think it very difficult indeed given that the speeds of the craft will not be exactly the same and they will have very limited propulsion and guidance systems.

Comment: There is [space.se] for questions about space exploration.

Comment: Note to dock you want a very low relative speed.  It would be very difficult to match velocities (not to mention position) so closely over any significant distance.

Comment: Thank you @StephenG, I understand that this is difficult. I am looking for an answer that will try to estimate an attempt to calculate the required precision to achieve it while taking the decades journey into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect them before they accelerate, then sure, but they're no longer nano-spacecraft. To connect them after they accelerate, even with maneuvering thrusters, you wouldn't have enough delta-v to get them very close considering the speed.

At 20% of the speed of light, if you sent two off *at the exact same angle, a millisecond* apart, they'd be 60 kilometers apart for the duration of their journey. If they were off in angle by just one arcsecond, by the time they arrived at alpha centauri 4.367 light years away, they'd be 200 million kilometers apart.

In other words, as Scotty quite aptly put it in the 2009 Star Trek movie, it's "like trying to hit a bullet with a smaller bullet whilst wearing a blindfold, riding a horse."

Comment: I think you are overestimating this. You are not taking into account the time you got for this mission. Maybe it's possible to connect them within a year or a decade, especially if we can make the first spacecraft slightly slower than the following.

Comment: [Astronaut propulsion units](https://bit.ly/3oJoz4s) take up liters of space, most of which is dedicated to maneuvering, and only have a few dozen to a few hundred kph of delta-v. If you had a device with the majority of the space taken up by payload, you'd have a really hard time getting delta-v over a few kph, but let's say you achieved 10kph on a 1-gram device. 20% of c is 215,850,570 kph. Divide the two and you see that to get two nano-spacecraft to zero relative velocity, you'd need your initial acceleration to be accurate to _46 parts per billion_. Sounds like Scotty was spot on

Comment: @S.McGrew, how about accelerating the first spacecraft to a slightly slower speed than the second one. Also, allow a big gap between the launches, maybe minutes apart. Then even with a little maneuvering, you will be able to make contact. I think it's more of a problem of accuracy than energy and fuel.

Comment: Exactly, though the two can be traded off for each other. If you had an extraordinarily precise means of aiming and accelerating your spacecraft initially, you could reduce the energy requirements to almost nothing, probably arbitrarily small. Likewise, if you could engineer an impossibly large amount of delta-v (space units roughly equivalent to energy or fuel) into your spacecraft, you could overcome an arbitrarily large amount of imprecision in the aiming and acceleration. The ultimate problem is both the energy required and the precision required are far, far beyond our current technology

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not feasible to try to physically connect multiple nano-spacecraft after they've been accelerated. They will be accelerated sequentially, a few minutes apart.  If they reach the same speed, they will end up separated by a distance on the order of ~0.6 light minutes.  One way or another it will be necessary to maneuver them to get them at the same place, at the same time, moving with the same velocity, in order to connect them.  Nano-spacecraft just don't have the capacity to to carry engines for maneuvering.

Comment: What about moving on the same path? So there will be no physical connection, but they all will line up behind a shield that will protect them from some of the dangers of this journey?

Comment: It's barely conceivable, but a very unlikely.  The launch point - the Earth - moves in its orbit at 67,000 miles per hour while the Earth spins at about 1000 miles per hour at the surface. The nanocraft all would be launched from points thousands of miles apart - measured in a direction roughly perpendicular to the nanocraft's path. There is very little leeway for guidance during launch.